# Google Map ios sdk does not work in device, but work in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google ios sdk v1.2.2. I have created a very basic code to show google map view, which works fine in simulator both on iPhone and iPad. But when I try to run the same code in device (iPad 2, iOS 6.0). I get the following error.

'GMSException', reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS requires GoogleMaps.bundle to be part of your target under 'Copy Bundle Resources

I checked on internet and others post on stack overflow. It recommends to put GoogleMaps.Bundle from resources folder to your project folder, I have already did that, what else I can do to fix that error.

Comment: Ok Fixed it now, you have to go to "Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources -> Add", and then select the bundle from file browser. Hope it helps to others too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't added the bundle to the framework list.

Select the target and go to Build Phases, then in 'Link Binary with Libraries', hit '+' then Add Other.  Select the bundle in the file browser and then retry.

Comment: Hi, I added that way too, but still same error, but funny thing is it works fine in iOS simulator 6.1

Comment: Ok Fixed it now, I have added the comment instead of "Link Binary with Libraries" , the option is Copy Bundle Resources.